# Why cant i upgrade my spring mvc project with new version of lib?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment;

I changed the spring lib from version 3.0.1 to 4.3.2.
While running the project I'm getting the above error!!!

Comment: Reimport dependencies.

Comment: You will need to refresh the project from your updated Maven config and then completely clean and rebuild after changing a dependency.

Comment: Hi  @Jim Garrison I'm not using maven and this is just a small project of which i haven't build but running on my local tomcat server.

Comment: You must still recompile all the Java files against the new libraries, and also make sure the new libraries are available to your Tomcat server.